# 1.3.0 - Performance of SDF File Structure - Redundancy in Reloading Description Files For Every SDF Read?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recently checked out the source code of Gazebo 1.3.0 (`02a2ec16375a+ (gazebo_1.3) gazebo_1.3.0`) and was looking into how the XML and SDF system works. I noticed that for each SDF file is loaded (from `gazebo/Server.cc:`, `Server::LoadFile()`, then from `gazebo/sdf/interface/parser.cc:616`, `readXml()`), it makes multiple calls to `sdf::init()`. When debugging, it would load the same SDF description files (in `gazebo/sdf/1.3`) several times.

This seems like it might be redundant and inefficient. Are there plans to cache these loaded XML documents, or are there reasons why they are reloaded every time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/494/1.3.0---performance-of-sdf-file-structure---redundancy-in-reloading-description-files-for-every-sdf-read?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The current plan is to generate C++ class from the SDF description files at compile time. This will bypass touching the filesystem, and also bypass a lot of string based searching.

Look for this in Gazebo 1.4

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on 2012-12-12**:
Ah, makes sense. Thank you.